# How to move down background image?

Tags: templates, css, joomla-3.5

How can I move down the background image,so the word OUTSOURCING would be just below the logo? I think with video bg I have the same issue too... Top part of it is too high up.

http://idevsky.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the following file:

> templates/jp-x2/css/custom.css

and add:

```
body {
    background-position: top center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar for inspect your source code of your site in your browser.

A tool like this will give you information about the selectors and the path where they are located, the line number and the name of the file that contains this selectors.

Once you have this you can add or change the values, in this case you have this class:

```
background: #FFFFFF url(http://idevsky.com/images/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Here you can change for example the value **center center** to something like **center top**.

Please check more information here:

- [Background position.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)